# Regex expression for string "offerDate(1, 30)"

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string `"offerDate(1,30)"`. I have to check if my string start with `"offerDate"` and if this condition is true I have to extract 1 and 30 from the string. Could any one help me out. Thanks in advance.

My code is

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches("StingToBePassed",@"\d+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => Convert.ToInt16(x.Value))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Please describe what is the problem with your current code

Comment: I just wanted to check if my string starts with "offerDate".  And if its true then only the I need to store the number. The current code extract the number and store in the list, however it does not check if the string starts with "OfferDate"

Comment: To clarify, can "StringToBePassed" contain _multiple_ instances of `offerDate(1,30)` or only one? My updated answer assumes multiple based on your use of `Match`, but if that assumption is wrong I can revert to my original version which only parsed a single instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groups to extract specific parts of a larger pattern. In your case:

```
offerDate\((\d+),(\d+)\)
```

Which you can then wrap into a function:

```
static IEnumerable<Range> ParseOfferDateRanges(string input)
{
    var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"offerDate\((\d+),(\d+)?\)");

    return matches
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(ParseOfferDateMatch)
        .ToList();
}

static Range ParseOfferDateMatch(Match match)
{
    var fromValue = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var toGroup = match.Groups[2];

    var to = toGroup.Success
        ? short.Parse(toGroup.Value)
        : (short?)null;

    return new Range()
    {
        From = short.Parse(fromValue),
        To = short.Parse(toValue)
    };
}
```

I've assumed you have a `Range` struct that looks like the following, though in C# 7 you could also return a tuple:

```
public struct Range
{
    public short From;
    public short? To;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It the same thing which I wanted.

Comment: No problem. If it answered your question, you can click the "tick" on my answer it will mark your question as "answered".

Comment: Thanks for your help. However is there any possibility that we can have the second parameter as optional. I mean if string "OfferDate(1,)" is supplied then also its matches the condition. We can definitely use two Regex expression but I want it to use a single expression

Comment: @AvinashRoy Updated. The second group in the regex is now marked as optional by appending a `?`, and the `ParseOfferDateMatch` has been updated to check if the group matched.

Answer (score 0):

you can try pattern with positive lookbehind feature:

`(?<=offerDate\((\d+,)?)\d+`

Note: you have to use `regex.Matches` (not just `Match`) in order to work.